# encryption password sha1 keySpring?

Tags: spring, authentication, hash, spring-boot, passwords

I'm working on a spring boot broject,i will encrypte my password with sha1 key wen an user will connected to my application but i don't have any idea how do it

Answer (score 1):

SHA1, in fact all cryptographic hash algorithms, are not encryption, they are one-way functions, there is no key, there is no reversal. Also SHA1 shod not be used in new work, SHA256 seems to be the current workhorse.

Further for passwords toy should use something like PBKDF2, bcrypt or script that include a salt and multiple iterations.